# vba regex - Get non space characters before space

Tags: regex, vba

So far I have this..

```
search_str = "-X made"
regEx.Pattern = "(\S*)[^\s*]"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = True
If regEx.test(search_str) Then
    Set matches = regEx.Execute(search_str) 
    extractStr = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
end if
```

I want extractStr to have -X ( anything before the first space), but I am not getting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with the pattern string `"(\S*)[^\s*]"`

1. <strike>Non-escaped backslashes in the String literal</strike> In this particular language, backslash escapes aren't necessary (thanks [Leviathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6216216/leviathan)<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955178/vba-regex-get-non-space-characters-before-space/36955207#comment61468582_36955207)</sup>)
2. `\S` and `[^\s]` are the same thing
3. `[foo*]` means match `f`, `o` or `*`

You probably want something like this

```
regEx.Pattern = "(\S+)(?=\s)"
```

Which means

- `(\S+)` match one or more non-whitespace (and remember the match) greedily until..
- `(?=\s)` the next character is whitespace

Please note that a string like `" "` will **not match**, if you want this to match too, use the zero-or-more `*` in place of the one-or-more `+`

---

If you want to **always match** and you want to **always start from the beginning of the *String*, the *RegExp* becomes something like this

```
regEx.Pattern = "^(\S*)(?=\s|$)"
```

Where

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `foo|$` matches `foo` or the end of the string

Comment: Thanks. This works except that it doesnt extra \ and that (\S+)(?=\s) is sufficient.

Comment: I don't think escaping the backslashes is necessary - nor correct! Using the *Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5* library your pattern will only work with single backslashes. Since they are meant as escape characters for the following `S` respective `s`, doubling them effectively escapes the backslashes so that the literal `\S` and `\s`remain in the pattern. Instead, you want them to stand in for spaces respectively non-spaces.

Comment: That's better! Also, for anybody curious how it works, `?=` is the `LookAhead` symbol, meaning you can specify what follows a pattern without it being part of the match.